# Can I use Eclipselink Moxy marshalling with delimitted files?

Tags: java, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I am using POJO un/marshalling via JAXB and EclipseLink MOXy and it works great for to/from JSON notation.

I also have a need to process a CSV file (well actually a pipe-delimited file, what do they call that?) where each row gets unmarshalled into my POJOs.

Perhaps some custom Adapter scheme perhaps?
( http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/moxy/advanced_concepts006.htm )

Answer (score 0):

Currently EclipseLink MOXy supports XML and JSON.  In order to support unmarshalling something like a delimited file, you could write something that converts the data to SAX events and then use that in combination with an `UnmarshallerHandler` obtained from the `Unmarshaller`.

Answer (score -1):

For prospective readers: you could consider to use [Jackson with dataformat csv](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-csv)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes